# gsheets script permission for a clear content button

Tags: javascript, google-sheets-api

I hope I added the right tags this is the first question I have asked.

Here goes... I made a gsheet workbook to calculate selling price by using gross profit margin. The calculations for the 'Calculator' are done on a separate worksheet 'Calculations' that links from the 'Calculator' and then back to the 'Calculator' once the calculations are performed.

I made a drawing of a button to clear the inputted data in the 'Calculator' by assigning a "Google Apps Script" to it. The button works great for me the owner but... when I use the 'Calculator' sheet as a shared editor I click the button and get this error.

"You are trying to edit a protected cell or object. Please contact the spreadsheet owner to remove protection if you need to edit."

I don't know how to change the permission for the script to get it to work for the share, please help. Here is the script.

```
    function clearRange2()
{
  //replace 'Calculator' with your actual sheet name
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Calculator');
  sheet.getRange('B9:B29').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('C10:C29').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('B3:B7').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('D4:D7').clearContent();
}
```

Comment: Please check to make sure that you've not turned on the protected ranges  (https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1218656)

Comment: I have protected certain cells so the user can only add data in the cells I want them to, but the drawing/button is not protected. I don't know even how you can protect the buttons script. Maybe you can shed some light or I could share the sheet with you.

Comment: Could you share *a copy* (not the actual one) of the sheet where we can repro the behavior? Also, could you verify if [the *other user* is properly logged in to a Google Account](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/docs/yLpz2Xsdddw/rJAivhqwCwAJ) when attempting to use the button?

Comment: I just change my sharing settings so I can copy a link waiting for it to change for my Google Apps domain

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JGJ3A-Gun6Qq4--njY0UqwMYzqXzv14EO7m_48Y2Tns/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I checked out the link you gave me to see if users are properly logged in. looks like it refers to a user trying to edit a range of cells that is protected in a spreadsheet. I have a drawing with a button that  has a script attached to it so it is not a cell. maybe if i could attach a script to a cell to clear contents it would work better. Any ideas?

Comment: if you want to do this  securly without user permission then try  to create some user friendly editing without break protection by assign script in drawing  object are as following link.  https://youtu.be/rOrq0m7xm6g